# Primefaces - RequestContext Update

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Olá,
Ao carregar a página o metodo `iniciarTeste()` será chamado da seguinte forma:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{testeController.iniciarTeste()}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Na mesma página tenho o campo `nome` que eu gostaria de carregar com o valor atribuido em `testeController`

```
<ui:define name="body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-default">
                <h:form id="testeForm" name="testeForm">
                <div class="box-body">
                   <div class="form-group col-md-12" id="divNome" name="divNome" >
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{testeController.nome}" id="nome" />
                    </div>
      .
      .
      .
```

Segue o metodo:

```
Public String nome;

public void iniciarTeste() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.update("testeForm:nome");       
}
```

Fiz o teste também com:

```
context.update(":testeForm:nome");
```

Quando o update vai ser realizado:

```
Cannot find component for expression "testeForm:nome" referenced from "j_id1"
```

Sabe o que estou fazendo de errado? Ou alguma idéia de como posso fazer diferente?

Obrigado

Comment: Seu RequestContext é do [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.0/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html)?

Comment: Sim... **Primefaces** (`org.primefaces.context.RequestContext`).

Comment: Olá, experimente incluir o atributo `prependId="false"` no seu form. Ai no RequestContext ficaria assim `context.update("nome");` Informe se deu certo, ou se o erro continua.